# UITextField creates EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS 11.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, objective-c-blocks

In my application, When click a thumbnail image it shows in a larger view in another `viewController` with textfields to edit the properties of that image. If we click the thumbnails to view in larger and close continuously, after 3 or 4 times the app getting crashed.

And finally I found it was occurred due to textfield. So I removed the textfields and check, everything works fine.

I declared `UItextField` as weak property and assign delegates to that.

It was happened only in ios 11. Before that i had no issues. Please help me out from this.

Comment: can you share your code??

Comment: FirstViewController *firstViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“XXXXX”];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

This is my navigation code to larger view.

Comment: can you enable exception breakpoint and detect where ecactly the app getting a crash ? what does the debugger says on crash ?

Comment: Show your delegate methods